# How to create CAML query in powershell to compare dates?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, caml-query

I want to compare dates, but my code isn't working.

```
    $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
    $camlQuery = "<Query><Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='DocumentDate'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='False'>$expireyDate</Value></Lt></Where></Query>";
    $spQuery.Query = $camlQuery
    $sourceItems = $sourceList.GetItems($spQuery)
```

and the value of `$expireyDate` is `1/1/2008`. I want to get all items who's field value 'DocumentDate' (which is a date field) is less than the expiry date.

It just returns all the items in the list, and doesn't filter.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: How can I do that with another date column and not with a static date?

Answer (score 1):

```
[microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime($oneHourAgo)
```

One other thing important to know is that you will have to include the following property in your query:

`IncludeTimeValue=”True”`

And here is a script example:

```
$web = get-spweb http://site.domain.com/sites/yoursite
$SPList = $web.lists["yourList"]

$now = get-date
$oneHourAgo = $now.addhours(-1)

$spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spqQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope = 'Recursive'"
$spqQuery.RowLimit = $SPList.ItemCount

$spqQuery.Query = '<Where><And><And><Geq><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="True">' + [microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime($oneHourAgo) + '</Value></Geq><Eq><FieldRef Name="Some_Status" /><Value Type="Text">Created</Value></Eq></And><Lt><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="True">' + [microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime($now) + '</Value></Lt></And></Where>'

$SPListItems = $SPList.GetItems($spqQuery)

foreach ($splistitem in $splistitems) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create date in ISO format (Ex: -`2015-06-04T02:32:20Z` as below

```
$expireyDate = [microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime($expireyDate);

$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
$camlQuery = "<Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='DocumentDate'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='False'>$expireyDate</Value></Lt></Where>";
$spQuery.Query = $camlQuery
$sourceItems = $sourceList.GetItems($spQuery)
```

Comment: I tried it, result was `<Query><Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='DocumentDate'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>2008-01-01T00:00:00Z</Value></Lt></Where></Query>` but it still got all documents.

Comment: See my updated answer. You dont need to add `Query`

Comment: It is still getting all items.

Comment: `<Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='DocumentDate'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='False'>2008-01-01T00:00:00Z</Value></Lt></Where>`

Comment: Remove `IncludeTimeValue='False'`

Comment: It is still getting same items.

Comment: It seems some other issue. Can you post complete code. Also try CAML query using CAML Query builder and double check.